# Parallel For over shared array without using lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

What is the best approach for modifying the content of an array of value types in a `Parallel.For` loop, where each task may potentially modify the data for the same index.

In the code below the `sum_normals` array will not always contain the correct summation values.

I could use a lock but I found it would be faster to just run synchronously. Create a dictionary with a value a concurrent bag and use aggregation/sum to calculate the sum in another loop.

```
var sum_normals = new Vector3[Count];

Parallel.For(0, list.Count, options, i =>
{
    var index_1 = ...
    var index_2 = ...
    var index_3 = ...
    Vector3 normal = ...

    sum_normals[index_1] += normal;
    sum_normals[index_2] += normal;
    sum_normals[index_3] += normal;
});
```

Comment: You should avoid putting yourself in this position in the first place.  Dealing with shared mutable state in a multithreaded environment is *very* difficult to do well.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is `Vector3` one of the SIMD classes in .NET 4.6.2? Your code is trying to modify three `Vector3` instances at each step, which seems like a very strange thing to do. The accelerated usage is the *opposite* - modify all 3 elements of the class with a single command.

Comment: In any case, you should use either PLINQ or manually partition the data so that you *don't* need to modify the same elements from multiple tasks.

Comment: Please post the code that calculates the indexes and `normal`. Are you using [System.Numerics.Vector3](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector3(v=vs.111).aspx)? Wouldn't it make more sense to arrange your values so that you can use SIMD operations to modify all 3 elements at once, eg with `su_normals[single_index] += new Vector3(normal);` ? Or use one of the *Matrix* classes like [Matrix4x4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.matrix4x4(v=vs.111).aspx) in order to modify multiple `Vector3` elements at once?

Comment: Apologies, Vector3 is indeed a SIMD class. The code simply calculates the surface normals of a mesh from a list of triangles. Since vertices can be visited multiple times the calculation basically needs to do a running sum (which is later normalized).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parallel.For` [has an overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783586(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows for functions that run at thread start and thread end (more than 1 iteration of the `body` function may execute over the lifetime of the thread). In these functions, you can create a local storage to write to then add that local storage to the group storage in the cleanup phase.

```
var sum_normals = new Vector3[Count];

Parallel.For(0, list.Count, options, 
    () =>  //localInit
    {
        return new Vector3[sum_normals.Length];
    },
    (i, loopState, localArray) => //body
    {
        var index_1 = ...
        var index_2 = ...
        var index_3 = ...
        var normal = ...

        localArray[index_1] += normal;
        localArray[index_2] += normal;
        localArray[index_3] += normal;

        return localArray;
    },
    localArray => //localFinally
    {
        lock(sum_normals)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < sum_normals.Length; i++)
            {
                sum_normals[i] += localArray[i];
            }
        }
    });
```

Note depending on the amount of work being done in the `...` it still might be faster just not to do this in parallel.

Comment: Right, this is pretty much what I was looking for. Unfortunately it's about twice as slow so my guess is that unless I modify the way I partition the list it will just have to not run in parallel.